# How to disable the + (add) button in detail grid?

Tags: acumatica

I have created a Master-detail custom screen and is there any way i can disable add (+) to prevent entering record in detail grid with out entering data in master?

[image]

At present both Location & Location color add button enabled and it allows to enter records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
DetailsView.AllowInsert = MasterView.Select().Count>0;
```